# Transition delay CSS3

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have some slider with images.

If I will put mouse on some slide it will just show the image and the image should be without grayscale efect. But I want to have transition delay for changing this efect.

How can I specify that on hover on the li element in which is the image will change the image inside using transition delay:

```
.grayscale
{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease; /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Fix for transition flickering */
}


.grayscale:hover
{
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}



<li class="kwick grayscale"><!-- using it here will slow down slide effect -->
<a href="' . $article['url'] . '">
    <div class="kw_shadow"></div>
    <div class="kw_title">' . $article['title'] . '</div>
    <div class="kw_img">
    <img src="' . $article['imageSrc'] . '" alt="' . $article['title'] . '" style="width: 960px; height: 400px;" class="grayscale" /><!-- using it here will apply grayscale if I'm with my mouse fxp on the bottom on right side -->
    </div>
</a>
</li>
```

Here it is live: http://www.sczdavos.eu/

Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to put `-webkit-transition-delay` at the end. Otherwise, it won't work.

This works

```
.kwick a:hover img.grayscale{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay:2s;
}
```

This doesn't

```
.kwick a:hover img.grayscale{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-transition-delay:2s;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
}
```

Comment: Try put mouse on the bottom of current slide - it will apply grayscale on the image. But I want apply grayscale only for inactive slides. So I need apply this efect if mouse is on the li element in which is current slide. And I want have fade efect - slowly apply effect. But I dont want slow down slide efect.

Answer (score 0):

May be  -webkit-transition-delay property can be helpful for you,

try this:

```
.grayscale img {
    transition-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand you. This is what I just have in my example. My problem is that I want add this transitioin just only for image not for slider.

Comment: Can you rephrase this line please "How can I specify that on hover on the li element in which is the image will change the image inside using transition delay"

Comment: Try put mouse on the bottom of current slide - it will apply grayscale on the image. But I want apply grayscale only for inactive slides. So I need apply this efect if mouse is on the li element in which is current slide. And I want have fade efect - slowly apply effect. But I dont want slow down slide efect.